# mysql select data from multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table

```
id, name, keyword
1   bob    guy
2   bob    developer
3   mary   girl
4   joe    guy
```

**Q1 :** What would be the sql to get back the row (bob) containing both keywords 'guy' AND 'developer'?

Intuitively, I thought it'd be `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE keyword = 'guy' AND keyword = 'developer'`

**Q2:** But I suppose the first conditional `AND` removes the 2nd row (bob, developer) which causes the sql to return no result? Am I correct about this speculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE keyword = 'guy' AND name in (SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE keyword = 'developer')
```